# $P_y = Q_x$ but $P_x, Q_y$ not continuous?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Stewart - Calculus

---

[image]

---

Suppose all the assumptions hold but $P_x$ or $Q_y$ is not continuous, is the conclusion necessarily false?

If so, why? Also, please give an example.

If not, please give an example where the conclusion still holds.

Comment: Then this theorem does not hold. Anything else?

Comment: It mentions in the theorem that it holds only if the partial derivatives are continuous. Do you want some proof?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Edited question

Answer (score 0):

We don't need $P_x$ or $Q_y$ continuous, but at least one of $P_y$ or $Q_x$ continuous. For an example consider the function
$$f(x,y):=\left\{\eqalign{&{x^2y-xy^3\over x^2+y^2}\qquad(x^2+y^2\ne0) \cr &0\qquad\qquad\ \qquad(x=y=0)\cr}\right.$$
Then ${\bf F}:=\nabla f$
is a conservative vector field with
$$P(x,y)={x^4y+4x^2y^3-y^5\over(x^2+y^2)^2},\quad Q(x,y)={x^5-4x^3y^2-xy^4\over(x^2+y^2)^2}\qquad(x^2+y^2\ne0)$$
and $P(0,0)=Q(0,0)=0$ (check this!). One now computes
$$P_y(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}{P(0,h)-P(0,0)\over h}=\lim_{h\to0}{-h^5/h^4\over h}=-1\ ,$$
and similarly $Q_x(0,0)=1$.